# handle php echo from mootools jsonp

Tags: php, jsonp, mootools

I everybody,
I have a script for newsletter signup "signup.php" that accept GET data like:

```
www.miosito.it/iscriviti.php?username=miousername&email=miaemail
```

If email and username is ok, isciviti.php end with: "echo(good)", otherwise end with "echo(bad)".

I need to handle the echo messages from signup.php with MooTools (jsonp)? and i cannot modify iscriviti.php script.

I have tried with:

```
var myRequest = new Request.JSONP({
    url: "http://www.miosito.it/iscriviti.php?username=miousername&email=miaemail"
}).send();
```

but i don't know how to get the bad or good messages.

Comment: What makes email and username "good" and what makes it "bad"?

Comment: If email is in invalid format iscriviti.php end with echo(bad), if email is alredy registered iscriviti.php end with echo(dejavue) else iscriviti.php end with echo(good).

Comment: Did you try to add a "onSuccess" function to the Request? like `onSuccess: function(responseText){
        alert(responseText);
    }`. Is the signup in the same domain as the the url of the Request?